# Посоветуйте литературу по php, ООП и фрэймворкам

Tags: php, книги

Здравствуйте.

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, литературу по `php`, на которую стоит обратить внимание. Т.е. интересуют книги с хорошим грамотным кодом и описанием. Книги, на которые стоит потратить время и деньги.

Особенно интересует:

- ООП в `php`;
- `smarty`;
- `Yii`, `symfony` и `zend` фрэймворки;
- Программная архитектура (основы, принципы построения патернов, составление
     архитектуры в целом);
- Книги по следующим cms (drupal, wordpress, cmsmadesimple).

Интересует больше бумажная литература, но ссылки на документацию будут также плюсом (кроме официальной, ее нагуглили и прочли).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Номер раз [PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Objects-Patterns-Practice-Experts-Source/dp/143022925X).

Номер два [Zend Framework: разработка веб-приложений на PHP](http://www.books.ru/books/zend-framework-razrabotka-veb-prilozhenii-na-php-1728368/?show=1).

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос слишком обширный.

Фреймворки и CMS разные вещи, самое интересное в вопросе нет ничего про БД, ни про какую.
Из этого следует - либо знаешь БД в полном объеме, либо просто забыл упомянуть тут.

Книг куча - в каждой описано по разному, у меня по ооп php около 7, в каждой все по разному преподнесено, в какой-то что-то лучше, что-то хуже. Из-за этого их так много и есть.

Фреймворки - вообще пока стоит забыть, если только на начальной стадии находишься. Ничего не поймешь, голову забьешь - выхлоп  нулевой.

Программная архитектура - атасно звучит. [тут](http://citforum.ru/SE/project/pattern/) много букаф.

В инете с каждым годом информации в Эл виде все больше и больше. Я вот когда начинал был только [php.net](http://php.net) на Eng. и вот крутились же. Сейчас этого добра много. Если есть желание и мозги то все встанет на свои места, но нужно думать и шевелить мозгами иначе трата времени, сил, денег. Задавать друзьям более правильные вопросы и получать направление вектора по которому будешь решать вопрос, привыкни делать сам, а не просить чтобы сделали за тебя иначе это все фигня и ничему не научишься!

у меня все

**//upd**
http://butteff.ru это твой блог? Если да, то что за глупый вопрос ты вообще задал.
Ты же "начальник" студии своей

в блоге много воды, и ты сам в ней плаваешь

вопросы у тебя и по **c# windows7 c++** и **по php wordpress mysql jquery javascript** сам-то определился с тем в какую сторону будешь программировать? или специалист широкого профиля?

Comment: полность согласен) начинай с азов) а потом уже к фреймворкам переходи чтоб смог понимать чужой код и делать не костыли а красивые вещи в плане добавления функционала на существующие классы

Comment: ну тут речь не идет для людей с нуля. Напротив.

блог мой, а книги не для меня, а для всей команды.
А вопросов много, т.к. опять же, команда и взаимовыручка. если кто-то где-то запнулся, помогаем и ищем решение проблемы все вместе.

Answer (score 0):

ООП в `РНР`, на мой взгляд, хорошо описано у Кузнецова и Симдянова, ищите самые последние их книги, т.к. `РНР` очень быстро развивается.

По популярным фреймфоркам часто можно найти документацию на русском прямо на офсайте.
Рекомендую еще поискать видео уроки в торрентах.

Книг по Дизайну кода `aka` Программная архитектура с примерами на `РНР` не видал.
Что касается дизайна кода для `web`-приложений, тут смотрите внутренности фреймворков.
Причем все динамично развивающиеся `CMS` в основе тоже содержат фреймворки, которые чаще называются `API CMS`.

Книг по CMS на русском чрезвычайно мало, хотя по Друпалу можно найти видео с конференций, которые проходят ежегодно в больших городах России. Тут по книгам только могу посоветовать учить английский. На английском таких книг завались в сети.

Comment: книги по друпалу на русском imho нет большого смысла читать, если идет речь о девелопменте естественно, а не управлением контентом, т.к. книги переводятся с большим опозданием и перестают быть актуальными еще до выхода в печать. Новая версия судя по статьям вообще будет использовать элементы symfony2, так что тут можно посоветовать только отдельные туториалы плюс немножко мозгов и усидчивости для копания в коде